# How to extract a model out of another trained model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have trained a model that looks like this:

```
Input -> Dense_1 -> Dense_2 -> Dense_3 -> Dense_4 -> Output
```

I want to extract a model so that I can pass an input directly to Dense_2 so my Model would look like

```
Input (In the correct shape for Dense_2) -> Dense_2 -> Dense_3 -> Dense_4 -> Output
```

All the techniques I saw are initializing a Sequential model and concatenate the models together e.g.

```
Input -> Dense_1 -> Sequential
```

But that won't work for my case.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy with the Keras functional API. First define a model:

```
inp = Input(shape=(...))
d1 = Dense(..., name='d1')(inp)
d2 = Dense(..., name='d2')(d1)
d3 = Dense(..., name='d3')(d2)
out = Dense(..., name='d4')(d3)

model = Model(inp, out)
```

Then get the input of a layer and build a new model.

```
inp_d2 = model.get_layer('d2').input

sub_model = Model(inp_d2, model.output)
```

Note how I put layer names manually so you can find them layer using `get_layer`.

Comment: my layer d2 in this case was a lambda function and this code is returning an error.

Comment: Ok you didn’t mention that earlier. But it shouldn’t be a problem with the functional API. Maybe post a minimal example of your specific model.

Comment: @user99355 But you told us it was a Dense, you need to make sure that the information in your question is correct and represents the use case. You should update your question  and include the error message here in this answer as a comment.